# Applying background color to the <tr> tag for the selected row in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I am displaying the records from the custom object using the HTML table in LWC.
I am using this below tag to iterate over the list of records.
I want that on click of a row the background color of the gets change and when I click another row then the background color of that row gets changed.

```
<tbody>
  <template for:each={testList} for:item="test" for:index="idx">
   <tr class={test.rowSelected} key={test.Id} data-id={test.Id} onclick={handleClick}>
    <td>
     {test.name}
    </td>
   </tr>
  </template>
 </tbody>
```

JS

```
import getTestList from '@salesforce/apex/TestClass.getTestList';
@track testList
@track rowSelected;
@wire(getTestList)
wiredlist({data, error}) {
  if(data) {
    this.testList = data;
    this.error = undefined;
  } else {
    this.error = error;
    this.testList = undefined;
  }
}

handleClick(event){

  this.testList.forEach(row =>{
    if(row.Id === event.currentTarget.dataset.id){
        row.rowSelected = 'row-color'
    } else {
        row.rowSelected = '';
    }
  });
 }
```

CSS

```
.row-color {
 backgorund: blue;
}
```

When I click on  any row, all row's background-color gets changed and not just the one which I clicked.

Can anyone help on how to apply the style on the current item in the html table?

Comment: Where's your JavaScript?

Comment: You have a typo, you used both `Id` and `id`. Presumably, it should be one or the other.

Comment: Have you thought about using CSS like "tr[data-selected="true"] { background-color: blue }" and adding the "data-selected" attribute to the selected tr? This would set the background on that row.

Comment: My apologies for the limited information, I have updated the code which I have written till now.

Comment: The fundamental issue you have is that all the generated rows receive the rowSelected value in their class attribute. You need to ensure that only the selected row gets this value set. The easiest way to do that is to ensure that your interated objects ("test") have a property that is set into the class attribute and only set it to "row-color" for the actual selected "test" instance.

Comment: data-selected attribute is not solving the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a single `rowSelected` class-level attribute. You need one for each of the rows.
And the `onclick` handler will setup that value when the row is clicked, also you need to reset the old one.

See the sample code.

```
@track testList = [{ Id: '1' }, { Id: '2' }, { Id: '3' }, { Id: '4' }, { Id: '6' }, { Id: '5' }];

handleClick(event) {
    this.testList.forEach(row =>{
        if(row.Id === event.currentTarget.dataset.id){
            row.rowSelected = 'row-color'
        } else {
            row.rowSelected = '';
        }
    });
}
```

Now on the HTML side, you just to assign that attribute the class using the `item` variable of the iterator.

```
<tbody>
    <template for:each={testList} for:item="test" for:index="idx">
        <tr class={test.rowSelected} key={test.Id} data-id={test.Id} onclick={handleClick}>
            <td style="height: 10px; width: 100px; border: 1px solid grey;">
                {test.Id}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </template>
</tbody>
```

**Note that the inline styles are not recommended here, I used them just for the demo purposes.**

Also, your CSS should be something like.

```
.row-color{
    background:lightcyan; // or whatever color you prefer.
}
```

You can also use the method suggested by @Phil W, `tr[data-selected="true"]` just that you will set the data attribute instead of the class with some modification.

**Update Based on the update in question.** 
You need to deep clone the data returned by the wired method like below. Using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`

```
@wire(getTestList)
wiredlist({data, error}) {
  if(data) {
    this.testList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    this.error = undefined;
  } else {
    this.error = error;
    this.testList = undefined;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your way,  but giving error as object is not extensible

Comment: You have to clone the data you get back from the server or you need to use an object that wraps each item back from the server and adds the per-row flag.

Comment: Tried but unable to do that. I created a field (kept it as empty) in the object also but that doesn't seem to get fetched.

Comment: @SFDCIN can you update your code in question?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code but this code is giving me error as  the object is not extensible. I tried to copy the testList in another object but again it was giving the error

Comment: @SFDCIN check the updated answer.

Comment: @RahulGawale this is ingenius. Thank you.